# Why can't I send message from indicator applet with evolution

Tags: indicator, evolution

My problem is, when I try to send a message with evolution using the indicator message applet's write new message option, after I click on the send message button, the window just disappears and my message is not sent.
If I open the main evolution window and click on send/receive then everything is ok. 
Is this a bug in evolution or do I miss something?
It seems like, when I use just the indicators quick sending option evolution quits before sending the message. Anybody has the same problem? Should I report this or it is a known bug?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bug/602974).

The message is queued and send as soon as you start evolution.